# Convert Java ArrayList of objects to scala seq

Tags: java, scala

I have `ArrayList` in Java which holds objects of type Row such as following

```
List<Row> Table = new ArrayList<Row>();
```

I need to convert this Table to Scala `Seq` in order to later convert it to data-frame. I tried the following without success

```
var TableScala:Seq[Row] = 
            Table.asScalaJavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(getTable).asScala

val newList = TableScala.map(row => new Tuple5(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4)))
spark.createDataFrame(newList).toDF("userID")
```

Answer (score 1):

From Scala 2.8.1, these conversions are made explicit using “scala.collection.JavaConverters._” api. The following code shows same conversion using this api.

First import

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

Java list

```
List<Row> javaList = new ArrayList<Row>();
```

Use “asScala “ to convert Java list to Scala list

```
val scalaList = javaList.asScala
val squareList = scalaList.map(value => value*value)
println("square list is" + squareList)
```

reference : http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/converting-java-collections-to-scala/

Comment: Thanks but I still can not convert squareList to data frame